# What StackExchange board is best for asking about setting up a linux server for VPN, Jira, GitLab and some VMs?

Tags: support

I am very far from being an expert in systems admin (I'm a programmer) but I want to set up my own private work environment with a VPN, Jira, GitLab and a bunch of VMs (some with linux servers, some with Windows) and I have no idea where to start asking the questions.

Do I use SuperUser? ServerFault? Is there a better forum elsewhere?

Comment: What would you ask precisely?  Questions should be specific, asking how you setup those services, is not specific enough.  That type of question, one that is not specific that is, isn't on topic on any StackExchange website.  Currently its not possible to answer this question, because even this question, is extremely broad.

Comment: @Ramhound The reason I'm not sure where to ask is that I need to ask the more general, "What is the best way to achieve this?" I have only 1 server, so it all needs to live on there, but I don't know if I should install a base linux server and do all the services as separate VMs (or containers, etc) or some other setup.

Comment: "What is the best way to achieve this?" that's opinion based, so also not on topic on any stack.

Comment: @DavidPostill Is there any forum where asking the proper/best way would be appropriate?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of forums. SE is not a network of forums. Opinion based questions are off-topic on all the SE sites I've looked at ...

Comment: I never find questions like, **What is the best way to achieve this?**, to be helpful.  If I see a question like I vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that that's pretty broad. You're going to have to break down the problem into a few parts and see what serves the best.

"I have no idea where to start asking the questions." is a problem.

"How to install" something is generally best served by the install guides for the software. Especially with commercial software.

"The best way" is opinion based.

And well, its a matter of taste. There's simply a lot of *good* options on how to do things. I tend to run my services clustered together on VMs as needed atop a linux box running KVM. I could have gone with ESXi as a hypervisor or run everything in docker and so on.

This might work on chat, but there's no chatroom which I know of where you can walk in and ask for help in designing an environment like that.